# Copy WordPress Password To Another Table With SHA1

Tags: md5, sha1

How can I copy WordPress password to another table with SHA1? As per my knowledge WordPress using MD5

Currently I am using simple query something like

```
INSEERT INTO rc_user(password)
SELECT user_pass
FROM wp_users
```

So I have no idea how to convert encryption. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. Both SHA1 and MD5 are hash functions and they do one way conversion of data so there is no way to "decrypt" it after md5 is applied.